# Tree not showing up when using TreeColumn

Tags: java, swt

I'm having trouble displaying a `Tree` which contains column definitions:

```
private Composite composite;
private Composite treeCompositeNdal;
private Tree treeNdalEditor;
private TreeColumn treeNameColumn ;
private TreeColumn treeValueColumn ;

[...]
treeCompositeNdal = new Composite(composite, SWT.BOTTOM);
treeCompositeNdal.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
treeCompositeNdal.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, true));
treeCompositeNdal.setVisible(false);

treeNdalEditor = new Tree (treeCompositeNdal, SWT.BOTTOM|SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

treeNdalEditor.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));
treeNdalEditor.setRedraw(true);
treeNdalEditor.setVisible(true);

treeNameColumn = new TreeColumn(treeNdalEditor, 0);
treeValueColumn = new TreeColumn(treeNdalEditor, 0);
treeNameColumn.setText("Name");
treeValueColumn.setText("Value");
```

The `Tree` displays fine if I comment out the `treeNameColumn` and `treeValueColumn` lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you call `.pack()` on both columns after adding your data?

Comment: BTW: `SWT.BOTTOM` is not a valid style for `Tree` and please use `SWT.NONE` instead of `0` for the `TreeColumn`s.

Comment: thank you Baz, the .pack() on both columns solved it. How do I vote your answer as a solution to the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [`TreeColumn#pack()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TreeColumn.html#pack%28%29) on both columns after filling in your content. This will force the `TreeColumn`s to resize according to their content.